# Two inputs in an ot-tableau with numberbed inputs and candidates

Tags: linguistics, ot-tableau

I'm intending to make a tableau with tikzpictures as candidates. Now I want to make both inputs (1 and 2) and candidates (a,b,c) numbered – I've tried using `mcand` but it says it's undefined.

The second question is how to make the numbers for candidates (a,b,c) on the top right of the cells?

```
\begin{tableau}{c|c|c:c} 
\inp{1. \ips{ \begin{tikzpicture} 
                \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
                \node(add) at (0.5, 0.5) {+};
                %\node (c) at (-0.2,0) {t};
                \node (v1) at (0,0) {o};
                \node (l) at (0,1.1) {$\texttt{H}$};
                \node (q) at (1, 0.5) {$\mu$};
                \node (ql) at (1, 1.1) {$\texttt{L}$};
                \draw (v1) to (mora1) to (l);
                \draw (q) to (ql);
                \end{tikzpicture}}}
              
\const{*3$\mu$}
\const{OCP}
\const{Max\textsubscript{T}}
\const{Max\textsubscript{$\mu$}}
%\const{Ident\textsubscript{T-$\mu$}}
%\const{Ident\textsubscript{$\mu-\sigma$}}

             
\cand[]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
                \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
                \node (v1) at (0,0) {o};
                \node (l) at (0,1.1) {$\texttt{L}$};
                \draw (v1) to (mora1);
                \draw (mora1) to (l);
                \end{tikzpicture}} \vio{} \vio{}\vio{*!}  \vio{*}
               



\cand*[]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
                    \node (a) at (0.25,-0.05) {o};
                    %\node (v1) at (-0.1,-0.05) {t};
                    \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
                    \node (mora2) at (0.5,0.5) {$\mu$};
                    \node (t) at (0.25,1.1) {$\texttt{H}$};
                    \draw (a) to (mora1) to (t);
                    \draw (a) to (mora2) to (t);
                    \end{tikzpicture}}
                    \vio{}\vio{} \vio{*!} \vio{} 
                    
\cand[\Optimal]{\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node (a) at (0.25,-0.05) {o};
                    %\node (v1) at (-0.1,-0.05) {t};
                    \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
                    \node (mora2) at (0.5,0.5) {$\mu$};
                    \node (t) at (0,1.1) {$\texttt{H}$};
                    \node (t2) at (0.5,1.1) {$\texttt{L}$};
                    \draw (a) to (mora1) to (t);
                    \draw (a) to (mora2) to (t2);
                    \end{tikzpicture}}
                    \vio{}\vio{} \vio{} \vio{} 

\inp {$2.$\ips{\begin{tikzpicture} 
                \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
               \node(add) at (0.35, 0.5) {+};
                %\node (c) at (-0.2,0.05) {b};
                \node (v1) at (0,0) {a};
                \node (l) at (0,1.1) {$\texttt{L}$};
                \node (q) at (0.7, 0.5) {$\mu$};
                \node (ql) at (0.7, 1.1) {$\texttt{L}$};
                \draw (v1) to (mora1);
                \draw (q) to (ql);
                \draw (mora1) to (l);
                \end{tikzpicture}}} 
                
%\const{*(LH)\textsubscript{$\sigma$}}
%\const{*3$\mu$}
%\const{OCP}
%\const{Max\textsubscript{T}}
%\const{Max\textsubscript{$\mu$}}
%\const{Ident\textsubscript{T-$\mu$}}
%\const{Ident\textsubscript{$\mu-\sigma$}}

             
\cand[]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
                \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
                %\node (c) at (-0.2,0.05) {b};
                \node (v1) at (0,0) {a};
                \node (l) at (0,1.1) {$\texttt{L}$};
                \draw (v1) to (mora1);
                \draw (mora1) to (l);
                \end{tikzpicture}} 
                \vio{}\vio{}\vio{*}\vio{*!}
\cand[]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
                \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
                %\node (mora2) at (0.5,0.5){$\mu_2$};
                \node (mora3) at (0.5,0.5) {$\mu$};
                %\node (c) at (-0.2,0.05) {b};
                \node (v1) at (0.25,0) {a};
                \node (t1) at (0,1.1){\texttt{L}};
                \node (t2) at (0.5,1.1){\texttt{L}};
                %\node (r) at (1,0) {r};
                \draw (v1) to (mora1) to (t1);
                %\draw (v1) to (mora2) to (t1);
                \draw (v1) to (mora3) to (t2);
                \end{tikzpicture}} 
    \vio{}\vio{*!}\vio{}\vio{}

  \cand[\Optimal]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
                %&$$#\node (c) at (-0.2,0.05) {b};
                \node (v1) at (0.25,0) {a};
                    \node (mora1) at (0,0.5) {$\mu$};
                    \node (mora2) at (0.5,0.5) {$\mu$};
                    \node (t) at (0.25,1.1) {$\texttt{L}$};
                    \draw (a) to (mora1) to (t);
                    \draw (a) to (mora2) to (t);
                    \end{tikzpicture}}
                    \vio{}\vio{}\vio{*}\vio{}            
\end{tableau}
```

This is what I have right now:
[image]

Comment: Sorry I should be on the top left of the cells!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Are you using the most recent version of the package? Do you have a local copy lurking somewhere? Also, please don't post code fragments. Instead, edit your question to show a compilable document that people can play with.